# [FATAL] Usage: rosrun message_to_tf message_to_tf <topic>

Tags: rviz, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i trying to move my robot in rviz,so when i put

```
<node name="odom_to_tf" pkg="message_to_tf" type="message_to_tf"> </node>
```

in my launch file i get  this error, how to fix it ?

```
[FATAL] [1567417863.872305532]: Usage: rosrun message_to_tf message_to_tf <topic>
[odom_to_tf-1] process has died [pid 28782, exit code 1, cmd /home/pavel/catkin_ws/devel/lib/message_to_tf/message_to_tf __name:=odom_to_tf __log:=/home/pavel/.ros/log/5d04e93c-cd65-11e9-94ce-d46d6d87b7ca/odom_to_tf-1.log].
log file: /home/pavel/.ros/log/5d04e93c-cd65-11e9-94ce-d46d6d87b7ca/odom_to_tf-1*.log
```

`rospack` output:

```
$ rospack find message_to_tf
/home/pavel/catkin_ws/src/hector_localization/message_to_tf
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/332158/%5Bfatal%5D-usage:-rosrun-message_to_tf-message_to_tf-%3Ctopic%3E/) by [Pakras](https://answers.ros.org/users/45316/pakras/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-09-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> [FATAL] [1567417863.872305532]: Usage: rosrun message_to_tf message_to_tf <topic>
> ```

As you can see from the error message printed, `message_to_tf` doesn't use ROS parameters for the `topic`, but expects a single argument on the command line.

The `<topic>` bit in the error message is something you have to provide.

In a `.launch` file, you can do that with the [args](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node#Attributes) attribute of the `node` element:

```
<node name="odom_to_tf" pkg="message_to_tf" type="message_to_tf" args="<topic>">
</node>
```

Be sure to replace `<topic>` with the actual name of the topic of course.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1